# Polygon right angles with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

In Google Mapmaker it's possible to draw polygons and in the edit state when you hold down shift it helps you to make right angles.http://www.google.com/mapmaker

When I try this in my own google maps where I enabled polygon drawings it's not possible to use the shift key to do this. Is there anything to enable this? It would be really useful.

This is what I use to make the polygons: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

Comment: Can you show the code with which you make the polygons?  I'll see what I can do.  btw. VUB student?

Comment: I added a link to what I make the polygons with. And no I am no VUB student I study in Eindhoven, Netherlands

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's the location that popped up when I clicked on your first link.  Must be Google doing that.